# Найти максимальную сумму элементов в массиве

Tags: массивы, алгоритм, олимпиада, динамическое-программирование

Есть массив massive с целочисленными положительными элементами . Есть условная переменная k - количество действий над массивом. Есть два типа действия: взять элемент massive[i] или передвинуться на massive[i+1].
Какую максимальная сумму элементов можно получить при заданном k? Начинать движение по массиву нужно с нулевого элемента, доходить до конца необязательно.
Пример 1:
massive = [5, 7, 11]
k = 3
Ответ: 12. Первым действием берем 5, вторым действием перемещаемся на 7, третьим действием берем 7.
Пример 2:
massive = [15, 17, 13, 20]
k = 2
Ответ: 17. Первый действием перемещаемся на 17, вторым действием берем 17.

Подскажите, как подобраться? Никак сообразить не могу.

Comment: а можно брать одно число несколько раз?

Comment: Если элемент имеете ввиду, то нет. Один раз взяли и все. А если повторояющиеся числа в разных элементах, то можно

Comment: Несколько соображений. 1) самый простой способ построить граф всех действий при k и посмотреть какая сумма будет наибольшей, брут форс, конечно 2) массив можно обрезать до k, очевидно, что дойти до k+1 и взять его мы не сможем, не хватит ходов.

Comment: По 2, да обрезать можно, если k меньше длины массива. Но насколько я понимаю, k может быть и больше длины массива

Comment: а откуда задачка, если не секрет?

Comment: соображение 3) насколько я понимаю вы не можете взять больше чем k/2 элементов массива, т.к. как даже если вы будете брать каждый элемент, то половина шагов будет съедена передвижением, т.е. как мне кажется, задачу можно свести к нахождению наибольшей суммы n<k/2 элементов массива min(k,a.length). 4) движение назад имеет смысл откинуть как нелогичное(только ест ходы), а двигаемся мы всегда вправо

Comment: п. 3 - глупость, т.к. можно сэкономить элементы на непоедании, сори

Comment: Точно не подскажу, коллега на работе рассказал, а она как назло в голову вцепилась:) думаю, что  откуда то по типу кодворса

Comment: Динамика по паре (позиция в массиве, количество оставшихся действий). Какие ограничения на `k` и длину массива?

Comment: 0 < k <= 20; 2<= massive.length <= 20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Динамика по паре (позиция в массиве, количество оставшихся действий).

Пусть `f(i, k)` - максимальная сумма которую можно набрать за `k` действий стартуя с позиции `i`. Для неё верны следующие соотношения:

> ```
> f(0, k)                            # искомая величина
> f(i >= len(a), *) = 0              # вышли за пределы массива a
> f(*, k <= 0) = 0                   # кончились действия
> f(i, k) <= f(i + 1, k - 1)         # двигаемся, a[i] не взяли
> f(i, k) <= a[i] + f(i + 1, k - 2)  # взяли a[i] и сдвинулись на шаг
> ```

Программа:

```
import functools


def max_sum(a, k):

    @functools.cache
    def f(i, k):
        if k <= 0:
            return 0
        if i >= len(a):
            return 0
        return max(
            a[i] + f(i + 1, k - 2),
            f(i + 1, k - 1)
        )

    return f(0, k)


print(max_sum([5, 7, 11], 3))
print(max_sum([15, 17, 13, 20], 2))
print(max_sum([15, 17, 13, 20], 100))
```

> ```
> $ python max-sum.py
> 12
> 17
> 65
> ```